# How to add a body to a https request in swift

Tags: swift

Im trying to add the following raw data to the code though im not sure how to go about that

```
fields name; limit 100;
where rating < 60;
```

To this code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    var loadUrl = URL(string: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games")!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        webView!.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView!)
        webView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView!.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        // Load first request with initial url
        loadWebPage(url: loadUrl)
    }

    func loadWebPage(url: URL)  {
        var customRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        customRequest.setValue("USER_API_KEY_HERE", forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
        webView!.load(customRequest)
    }

    // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        // If url changes, cancel current request which has no custom headers appended and load a new request with that url with custom headers
        if url != loadUrl {
            loadUrl = url
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            loadWebPage(url: url)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if its possible with the current way the code is formatted, should it have to change that is okay.

Comment: Well, change the `url`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can load a URLRequest and not a URL to your webView from the beginning. Like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414954-load).

And the URLRequest has [httpBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011390-httpbody) property where you can put a `Data`. The format is up to you.